# What do you call a mixture of 2 herbal drinks?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call a mixture of 2 herbal drinks? For example, butterfly pea extract and pandanus juice.

Comment: A mixture of blue-pea tea and pandan juice sounds like something I would call **vile**.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't call it a non-alcoholic cocktail, but it would probably depend on whether you were going to drink it recreationally, or as a health cure.

Comment: A herbal confusion?

Comment: @JohnLawler Funny pun! :) But on a side note, I think it should be _an_ herbal ..., am I right?

Comment: Isn't a mixture of two or more herbal drinks just another herbal drink? I don't see anything in the definition of *herbal* restricting it a single kind of herbs.

Comment: @MohammadSanei Depends where you are ... In the US, some people pronounce 'herbal' without a /h/ sound at the start, this may also be done elsewhere. In Britain, though, it's largely unknown and we pronounce it /ˈhɜːbəl/, so it should be *a herbal*. This pronunciation is used in many places, including the US I believe

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Viler still: a mixture of blue-pee tea and pandan juice.

Comment: A Potion maybe?

Comment: I have never heard of *butterfly pea* I envisaged a green pea with large wings, turns out the flower is of a cobalt blue colour, and it's also known as [*Asian pigeonwings*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Clitoria_ternatea.JPG) Me? I'm +1 just for the names of these exotic plants. Pandanus... what kind of weird fruit is that?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Butterfly peas are more commonly known as blue-peas (at least that's what I've always known them as), and _Pandanus_ fruits are mostly called pandans (the trees, apparently, are also called screw palms/pines). The fruits look quite a bit like durians, but taste worse (!!!). I think the pandan juice Lena was talking about here is rather from the grass of [_Pandanus amaryllifolius_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandanus_amaryllifolius), which is commonly used in Asian cooking.

Comment: What's wrong with simply calling it an "herbal mixture" or some such?  Why do you need a special word (that no one understands)?

Answer (score 33):

I've seen such mixtures referred to as concoctions (check the example below).

ODO:

> **[concoction](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/concoction)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** A mixture of various ingredients or elements:
>
> ‘The couple have to collect the herbs themselves and brew the
>   concoctions in earthen pots on low flame.’

Comment: I agree with this, with the caveat that it's not restricted to specifically a mixture of two "herbal drinks", and neither should OP expect a specific word for such a particular concoction :)

Comment: Then call it a "herbal concoction"

Comment: @monzoor: a concoction of *two* herbal drinks

Comment: Note that neither of the drinks in the OP is actually *herbal* by the traditional definition, so I might suggest ***vegetal** concoction*. This would also have the virtue of being less likely to be mistaken for something that you smoke.

Comment: I'd agree with this (was going to post it myself), but just to add that concoction may be seen as disparaging — *"What's in that concoction?"* doesn't sound like something I'd expect someone say if they liked the look of a drink :)

Answer (score 21):

**A blend**.

Note blend is used for mixtures of any substances - e.g. drinks.

> NOUN
>   1A. mixture of different substances or other things:
>   *‘the chutney is a blend of bananas, raisins, and ginger’.
>
>   ‘Ontario offers a cultural blend you'll find nowhere else on earth’*.
>   [...]
>   Origin. Middle English: probably of Scandinavian origin and related to Old Norse blanda to mix.
>   [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blend)

One particular usage is for whiskeys, which may be a interesting analogy for the OP's herbal drink requirement, especially if they can imply the herbal drink is created with similar care. Quoting Wikipedia :

> A **blended whiskey** (or blended whisky) is the product of blending different types of whiskeys and sometimes also neutral grain spirits, coloring, and flavorings. It is generally the product of mixing one or more higher-quality straight or single malt whiskies with less expensive spirits and other ingredients. This allows for a lower priced product, though expensive "premium" varieties also exist.
>   Some examples of blended whiskey include Canadian Mist, Jameson Irish Whiskey, Seagram's Seven American whiskey, the premium Japanese brand Hibiki and the premium Scottish brand variant Johnnie Walker Blue Label.

Answer (score 4):

You could call it a **drink**

> Liquid swallowed for assuaging thirst or taken into the system for nourishment (OED)

That it's composed of two "ingredients" or "sub-drinks"   is irrelevant to the use of the word.

You could also call it a **combination**:

> Combined state or condition of two or more things (OED)

Comment: Nice suggestion. I think it is better to put "combination" first.

Answer (score 4):

Colloquially, it could be called an "herbal cocktail". Just about any native English speaker would understand that to mean a mixture of herbs or herbal drinks, just like a "cocktail of drugs" means various drugs taken together.

Comment: A cocktail consists of three or more items. So while this is a good option in other cases it doesn't fit the OP's example.

Comment: @Rache do you have a reference for the "3 or more items" part ?

Comment: Actually, I have a reference telling me I shouldn't believe everything I see on TV. It seems that two-ingredient cocktails are fine. https://nightcapped.wordpress.com/2010/09/26/peggy-olson-defines-the-cocktail/
The original 1798 definition, "a stimulating liquor composed of spirits of any kind - sugar, water, and bitters," is at https://mrbostondrinks.com/history

Answer (score 3):

**Elixir**

> mid-13c., from Medieval Latin elixir "philosopher's stone," believed by alchemists to transmute baser metals into gold and/or to cure diseases and prolong life, from Arabic al-iksir "the philosopher's stone," probably from late Greek xerion "powder for drying wounds," from xeros "dry" (see xerasia). Later in medical use for "a tincture with more than one base." General sense of "strong tonic" is 1590s; used for quack medicines from at least 1630s.

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=elixir

Answer (score 1):

> #### Infusion
>
> **noun**
>
> 3. a liquid extract, as tea, prepared by steeping or soaking.

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/infusion))

This is a hypernym for any sort of herbal drink that is formed this way and would cover multiple drinks. It doesn't specifically cover a mixture but could be what you're looking for.

Comment: Although it's a good fit to the question title, *prepared by steeping or soaking* doesn't really work with the *juice* in the example gven in the question body

Comment: While I agree, `infustion` was the first word that sparng to my mind (so I upvoted this answer)

Answer (score 1):

You might call such a drink a **[tisane](http://coffeetea.about.com/od/teaandtisanebasics/a/TisaneBasics.htm) twosome**, if you're trying to be a smart-aleck. I would just call it an **herbal tea**. The fact that it's composed of multiple herbs is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe this hasn't been answered yet. I would call it a **potion**.

**noun**

> a mixture of liquids (as liquor or medicine)

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/potion)

Comment: "Potion" heavily implies that the liquid has magical properties (e.g, "healing potion"). I'm not sure it's applicable here.

Comment: I'm sure you could find books that state thise ingredients are good for some list of ailments.  There is a brand of pomagranite drink that makes it sound like it has handwavy health benifits.

Answer (score -1):

> #### Fusion
>
> **noun**
>
> that which is fused; the result of fusing:

*A ballet production is the fusion of many talents.*

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fusion))

---

**adjective**

> (of food or cooking) combining usually widely differing ethnic or regional ingredients, styles, or techniques:  a restaurant serving **French-Thai fusion** cuisine; a fusion menu.

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fusion))

Comment: This doesn't work. Concretely, fusion is typically the uniting of two metals by applying heat. Abstractly, it can be applied to food, but, as your citation states, this refers broadly to styles or cuisines.